# How to go from Terminal 4 to Terminal 1 at JFK during pandemic?

Tags: international-travel, airport-transfer, jfk

I am traveling solo to JFK and I will be landing at terminal 4 at 12:03 p.m. I have to get to my connecting international flight from terminal 1 at 2:00 p.m. on the same day. I need to know how to get from T4 to T1 in good time, and where is the transportation between terminals located?
Please note that I have no checked baggage, am traveling economy class and have American passport.

Answer (score 2):

You can take the AirTrain, which seems to be running regularly, at least according to https://www.jfkairport.com/to-from-airport/air-train. The Airport Terminals Loop is the best choice, since it runs clockwise, and has then only one intermediate stop between terminals 4 and 1. Between the terminals, the AirTrain is free of charge.